# SO not correctly displaying in Chrome?

Tags: bug, google-chrome

I don't know if this has already been posted yet and I can't find any posts that are the same, but Stack Overflow is not displaying correctly in Google Chrome. This happens on all 3 of my dev machines. I should mention I am in Japan, if that makes a difference.

And no, I can't scroll up to the the top of the page.

The question header seems to be cut off when displaying the question:

[image]

Is there a setting or something that needs to be done to correct this?

Comment: What Chrome/OS versions? Can you scroll up to the top, or is it entirely inaccessible?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. The latest version at this point in time.

Comment: Bearing in mind that what "this point in time" means is constantly changing, could you give an actual value?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, 2020-07-03 12:30:00.142 UTC

Comment: No repro on Windows 10, Chrome 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit), on both Incognito and with some extensions like uBlock Origin and some SE-related userscripts on Tampermonkey.

Comment: Or use the mouse wheel to scroll?

Comment: @KyloRen Not a value for the current time, but an actual Chrome version number. It's there in the About dialog. Always give a version number. "Chrome" describes literally hundreds or even thousands of distinct builds of browser. It takes you a few moments to write this detail, or us half an hour to pull it out of you ;)

Comment: I can't repro it. Try a ctrl+F5.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings OP is currently serving a year-long suspension and can't reply to you.

Answer (score 2):

It just looks like you haven't scrolled up all the way.  I cannot reproduce this on Firefox or Chrome, so you either have a problem you've not included in your post, or you're not scrolled all the way up.  Or, if you cannot use the scroll bar, press the up arrow key, or the <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> key.

Comment: + also I think the header is sticky , which I remember is a preference

Comment: cause some people don't like headers sticky?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV2YH.png actually turning it OFF is a preference. Who'd have thunk :D

Comment: The OP has specified that they are not able to scroll up. It would be better to delete this answer to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Still, it is better to write it as a comment because it seems that OP was not able to scroll in any way. Also, a comment is better than a possible wrong answer, and since the OP is suspended, they would not be able to verify its correctness.